# Error building tensorflow Android demo app on Mac

Tags: android, tensorflow

I exactly followed the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/) but the build still failed.:

This is what I did:

- Set up virtualenv, using python 2.7
- `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git`
- Update the WORKSPACE file with correct SDK/NDK directories.
- `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo`

It generates the following errors:

```html
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_feisun/a581ef40e662476b21101110ff9ad0b3/external/protobuf/BUILD:241:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@protobuf//:js_embed':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/embed.cc':
  '/Applications/Xcode_8.3.2_fb.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cassert'
  '/Applications/Xcode_8.3.2_fb.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__config'
  '/Applications/Xcode_8.3.2_fb.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include/stdint.h'
```

Searched a bit, maybe need to run ./configure. Then run the build command again. Same error.

Run: `git submodule update --init`, then run the command again. The error is changed to:

```html
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_feisun/a581ef40e662476b21101110ff9ad0b3/external/protobuf/BUILD:73:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@protobuf//:protobuf_lite':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc':
  '/Applications/Xcode_8.3.2_fb.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm'
  '/Applications/Xcode_8.3.2_fb.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__config'
  '/Applications/Xcode_8.3.2_fb.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/initializer_list'
```

I can't seem to build the demo app.

```html
 bazel version
Build label: 0.4.5-homebrew
Build target: bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Mar 16 13:39:33 2017 (1489671573)
Build timestamp: 1489671573
Build timestamp as int: 1489671573
```

```html
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode_8.3.2/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode_8.3.2/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```